# How to split a String and insert each value as a record in a database?

Tags: sql, database, file, jdbc, java.util.scanner

I am reading from a file where each line has 3-4 values that are separated by a tab. I have been trying to split the line up (based on the tabs) and store them in their own `String`, and then I push these values into a method that makes an `SQL statement` to `INSERT INTO` the values into a table as a new record.

My issue is that the `split()` method isn't quite working for me as it is giving me an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException' for the second value. But I am pretty sure there is an easier way to do what I am trying to do.

Currently I have:

```
// --------- Reading the topURLs file ---------
        
        try {
            scan = new Scanner (new File("TestURL"));
            
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine();
                String[] SQLValues = line.split("\\t");
                String rank = SQLValues[0];
                String websiteName = SQLValues[1];
                String domain = SQLValues[2];
                insertInto(conn, tableName, rank, websiteName, domain);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And my `insertInto`method in case you would like to see:

```
public static void insertInto(Connection conn, String name, String rank, String websiteName, String domain) {
        Statement st = null;
        
        int rankInt = Integer.parseInt(rank);
        try {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            st.execute("INSERT INTO " + name + "VALUES ('" + rankInt + "', '" + websiteName + "', '" + domain + "')");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am aware this is messy, it's just all I know so far. The `file` `TestURLs` currently has two lines for the sake of testing (they are split using tabs in my file, I just don't know how to show that on here):

> 1 google com
>
> 2 cheese com

Is there something I am missing that causes the `exception` mentioned above? I thought that when I `split` `line` that it would put each separated word in the a different index of the array `wordsArray`. Instead, it seems like there is only one element in it at index 0.

If there is a better way to do what I am trying to do - that is, to take a line from a file, split the values, and put them into a table as a new record - could you point me in the right direction?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There may be a third line or more in your file which may be empty or contains some kind of hidden text, like an end of file character or something. Hence, when you try to split by tab on that last line and there is only that character or it is empty space, you don't have an array with more than the zero index. Just use an if statement in your loop, check after split if the array length is the expected size, if so, continue the processing. `if(SQLValues.length >= 2)`

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
String[] SQLValues = line.split("\\s+");
```

you can use a greedy regular expression, which will match any number of white spaces including tabs. You can use "\s+" regex for this purpose.